# Php curl: https без сертификата

Tags: php, curl, https

Пробую получить страницу с помощью CURL в php. В ответе получаю такую ошибку

```
SSL: certificate subject name 'site.ru' does not match target host name '111.222.333.444'
```

Страница доступна по https, но сертификата нету. Это можно как то обойти?

Comment: Вы доступаетесь по IP? Если так, то нужно в URL писать site.ru

Comment: Нашел решение. Надо было прописать CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false